# CMIS Workbench Error running Query - Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, cmis, cmis-workbench

We are trying to run a simple query on a list (Sharepoint 2013) on Workbench but we are getting the "Connection:Redirects are not supported (HTTP status code 302):" error. What's weird is that we can run queries on other list except one named "AP Document".

We have also tried on on Visual Studio but is now getting the "Unauthorized error". With this we had set the permission to all lists to default but am still getting an error. We had also tried deleting the list and re-creating it but still no go.

What are we doing wrong with this one list?  Here's a log to check the codes. Please help.

> ERROR hemistry.opencmis.workbench.ClientHelper:
>   CmisConnectionException: Redirects are not supported (HTTP status code
>   302): Found
>   org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisConnectionException:
>   Redirects are not supported (HTTP status code 302): Found     at
>   org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.convertStatusCode(AbstractAtomPubService.java:460)
>     at
>   org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.post(AbstractAtomPubService.java:650)
>     at
>   org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.DiscoveryServiceImpl.query(DiscoveryServiceImpl.java:179)
>     at
>   org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionImpl$5.fetchPage(SessionImpl.java:887)
>     at
>   org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.util.AbstractIterator.getCurrentPage(AbstractIterator.java:132)
>     at
>   org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.util.CollectionPageIterator.hasNext(CollectionPageIterator.java:48)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it was a file within the list that was causing the error. When you try to run a query within that list that excludes that file -- everything works fine. 
Had to just remove and reupload it to fix the issue. but still curious why that is because the file can still be opened and viewed with no error on sharepoint but is getting the Unauthorize or Connection error when accessed thru CMIS...